# Optimize code for Android with multiple layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating an Android Application having two layouts. All layouts have some common features like the top part is same and the only difference is at the bottom part.

Currently I have created two separate java files for two layouts. And I have simply copied the code which implements similar functionality like buttons etc

[image]

The part seen is the pic is the top part of the layout which is same in both the layouts;

Is there any way with which I can optimize the functionality by having reusable code

Comment: Split the common parts out, use <include> in your layout

Comment: i was thinking of creating seperate classes for the reusable code.

Comment: Can we do something for the xml too??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion this is helpful using **`<include>`** in your main layout.

**STEP:**

you have to create one XML file for your common layout.

**topbar.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg">

     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

like this way now you have to include this XML file to where you have to require.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

     <include layout="@layout/topbar"/>   

      ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: am a bit confused with this line `<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/> `          how will it jnclude `topbar.xml?`   or its `topbar` in the line `<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>` instead of `titlebar`

Answer (score 0):

I think this tab bar can also be used for this..

below is the link for complete tutorial...

http://mindstick.com/Articles/7e659092-3046-4461-97ba-b2b28616241e/?tab%20layout%20android%20application